# What does "Run as hidden window" mean and how can I show the hidden windows?

Tags: windows

If we right-click the shortcut of an exe file, there are options to run the program as 'Minimized', 'Maximized', or 'Normal window':

[image]

NirSoft's [BulkFileChanger](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/bulk_file_changer.html) is able to do so too. But there's another option called 'Hidden':

[image]

When I run the programs as 'Hidden', they do not appear in my taskbar. Task Manager does show that the programs are running indeed.

**How** can I access / show those currently running 'Hidden' programs?

Also, exactly what does it **mean** to start main window as 'Hidden'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What "Hidden" means is exactly what you observe, that you cannot see its GUI and it has no presence on the task-bar.

Nirsoft's [nircmd](http://nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) allows you to hide, show and activate running windows. Use `nircmd win show` to reveal a hidden task, or `nircmd win activate` to show it and bring to foreground.

I find hidden windows most useful for background batch files, which would normally show up with a task-bar entry. If you want to interact with a task, don't hide it.

Comment: `show` doesn't work. I am able to `hide` and `togglehide` (which hides but never show), but once hidden, the processes never show up again. Is this a bug? Are you able to get a process hidden to `show`?

Comment: I'm able to show and hide tasks at will with NirCmd, whether or not I start the tasks using `nircmd exec`, but I don't use BulkFileChanger: since both are from the  same source, I assume that the programs use the same hiding mechanism. I'm testing NirCmd 2.41 on Win8.1 and I use the `ititle` option to specify the window.

Comment: You may find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28284876/what-are-the-different-ways-to-start-a-hidden-process-with-batch-file-and-what-a useful as guide to some of the mechanisms behind hidden tasks.

Comment: **Nice,** `ititle` works. This had to be a bug with `process`, because `nircmd win togglehide process notepad.exe` hides but don't show. Is the bug occuring on your setup too? After doing `nircmd win togglehide process notepad.exe`, the "Window" option is even greyed out in SysInternals process explorer:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/QynqV.png

Comment: You're right: I down-loaded the latest 64-bit version (2.41 has neither `togglehide` nor `process` options) and the `process` option works when hiding, but not when trying to show, whether the process name or the /PID format is used, so it seems like a bug. I had already noticed that tasks hidden by `nircmd` have the **Window** option greyed out in the Process Explorer context menu, as you have observed. Also, it appears that you can start hidden processes from Task Scheduler, but I've not tried this, so I don't know if they are hidden in the same way as `nircmd` hides tasks.

Comment: @Pacerier: You should report that bug to Nir Sofer.